# I can't import symbols in assembler

Tags: assembly, x86, static-libraries, unix-ar

I'm trying to write a static library for assembler. It's not working, though. The library builds fine, but when I try to build the program, this happens:

```
$ ld -o hello -L../myasm -lmyasm hello.o
hello.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `exit'
```

I poked around, and that further mystified me.

```
$ nm ../myasm/libmyasm.a
myasm.o:
00000000 T exit
$ nm hello.o
00000000 T _start
         U exit
00000000 d message
```

Any idea what's happening?

My code:

#### hello.s

```
#; This is a hello world program, in assembler.

.extern exit

.data
message:
    .byte 14
    .ascii "Hello, World!\n"

.text
.global _start

_start:
    #; First, write the message.
    mov $4, %eax            #; write syscall number
    mov $1, %ebx            #; stdout file descriptor
    mov $message+1, %ecx    #; message address
    mov message, %dl        #; we only want one byte, so %dl
    int $0x80

    #; Now, we need to exit.
    call exit
```

#### hello/Makefile

```
hello: hello.o
        ld -o hello -L../myasm -lmyasm hello.o
hello.o: hello.s
        as -o hello.o hello.s
run: hello
        ./hello
clean:
        rm hello.o hello
```

#### myasm.s

```
#; lib.s

.text
.global exit

exit:
    mov $1, %eax #; exit syscall #
    mov $0, %ebx #; success
    int $0x80
```

#### myasm/Makefile

```
libmyasm.a: myasm.o
        ar cr libmyasm.a myasm.o
myasm.o: myasm.s
        as -o myasm.o myasm.s
clean:
        rm myasm.o libmyasm.a
```

Comment: Try using `gcc` rather than `ld`. You didn't mention anything about the tools you're using, which makes it impossible to give a certain answer.

Comment: @Gene I posted my Makefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `hello`'s Makefile, move the object file `hello.o` before `-lmyasm` as:

```
hello: hello.o
        ld -o hello hello.o -L../myasm -lmyasm
...
```

see `-l` reference here of how the search of symbols is done, [3.13 Options for Linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html):

> ```
> -llibrary
> -l library
> ```
>
> ...
>
> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the
>   order they are specified. Thus, `foo.o -lz bar.o` searches library `z`
>   after file `foo.o` but before `bar.o`. If `bar.o` refers to functions in
>   `z`, those functions may not be loaded.
>
> ...